# How to make selection criterion on Roles in Lotus notes Views

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I would like to make a  selection criterion in Lotus notes Views base on the role the user belongs to, using the below code

> SELECT FORM ="User" & Retired = "0" |
>   (@IsMember("[Admin]";@UserRoles))

but whenever I check for the roles it return @UserRoles return an empty string "".
any idea how to go about criterion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use @UserRoles in a view selection. From Domino Designer help:

> This function does not work in column, selection, mail agent, or scheduled agent formulas.

You need to use readers fields. In your case, a document must have a readers field with [Admin] as a value.

Read more about readers and authors fields at [Using and understanding Reader Names fields in IBM Lotus Notes and Domino](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/reader-names/index.html) or [Reader and Author Field Troubleshooting](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Reader_and_Author_Field_Troubleshooting).

Comment: and how will the  selection criterion  look like

Comment: With readers fields, you don't need to limit the documents by user (or role) in the selection formula, so it would be SELECT FORM="User" & Retired = "0".  The Readers field does the rest.

Comment: What @Roman K says is correct, but you may want to use one view for people in the [Admin] role and another for other folks. We actually have a section in our apps that is only visible to the folks with [Admin] access. That way admins can see what the users see and also see what they need to see when they need to see it.